# Ajax: Getting Request Status And Update jProgressBar

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic, progress-bar

I have a task that extract zip files in file: `Update.asp`
How can I update jquery progress bar after task started on `index.asp`.

I found a solution that to use 2 ajax call at index.asp. one to start task with `update.asp` and another to get `session("progress_status")` which this Session changes when every extract file finishes on `update.asp`

```
<%
session("progress_status") = 0
'file 1 extracted
session("progress_status") = 50
'file 2 extracted
session("progress_status") = 100
%>
```

problem is when first ajax call starts, second ajax call remains pending until first call finish.

[my ajax calls](http://jsfiddle.net/LjGr9/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that the ASP processor will only process one script for a specific session at a time.  Hence your call to the asp script that attempts to get the progress will queue behind the asp script performing the extraction.

This is how I recommend you do it: fake it.  You make an ajax request to the page that does the extraction.  While its extracting you have a purely javascript driven progress bar that uses a timer.  Give it some easing so that appears to progress quite quickly at first but then exponentially slows down.  When the ajax request completes you can briefly show the progress bar as completed before removing it.

If you can acquire the original size of the zip you can use that figure to improve the match between faked progress bar and reality.  You could take this further if such extracts happen fairly frequently by recording some stats on the time take to extract various zip files to get some flavour time to bytes ratio.

Ultimately your users want the warm fuzzy feeling that something is happening and the above acheives that.